# How do I reference the center of a textblock with CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is a bit hard to explain but what I essentially want to do is have a short string of text be centralized inside a box indiscriminate to the length of the string.

If this is hard to understand check out the blue twitter hashtag box on this link: 
http://trendr.dk/pcph/overall.php

I want every hashtag to be 'centered' even though each hashtag has a different length.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really mean by centering hashtag, but I guess you want this;
change .tweetbox css to

```
.tweetbox { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 45%; 
     width: 100%; 
     text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant and simple. Thanks! Will accept answer as soon as 10min. passed.